# My mouse automatically changes themes

Tags: unity, gnome, mouse, themes

My mouse is set to a theme named DMZ-White i.e. the default theme in Ubuntu but ever since I installed and uninstalled deepin de my mouse becomes white only when it's on unity-greeter or firefox or some of the other apps. The other mouse theme that I don't want cannot be found in `/usr/share/icons/` but it has a black pointer and the watch icon is a black wrist watch
Can someone please tell me whats going on and how can I solve it.

**Note:** I have tried changing mouse themes but the they work the same as DMZ-White does i.e. only in some places and in the rest the same unknown theme appears

Comment: Does this also happen in the guest session???

Comment: No surprisingly it does not. Sorry I did not try it earlier i just assumed it

Comment: Hey, that's why we're here!!! Answer coming up!!!  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into the guest session and type the following commands: (assuming `user` is your old user name)

```
su - user
sudo adduser user2
```

and follow the instructions on-screen.  If you're *not on a US keyboard*, don't use any "special" characters like £ à ŷ ü nor any numbers unless they're from your keypad.

Now type the following commands:

```
sudo adduser user2 adm 
sudo adduser user2 cdrom
sudo adduser user2 sudo
sudo adduser user2 dip
sudo adduser user2 plugdev
sudo adduser user2 lpadmin
sudo adduser user2 sambashare
```

(If any of the above gives an error like `group not found`, don't worry: I'm trying to be thorough)

Now, log out of the guest session and log in as "user2" and come back here to this site.

Ah you're back!  ;-)  Please test now if you still have your problem...  No?  OK!

Now,

1. open the file manager
2. browse to the `/home/user` directory
3. **copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from Downloads to `/home/user2/Downloads`
4. check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/user/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for Documents, Videos, ...
7. In a terminal type the following command: `deluser user --remove-home`

## Done!

Comment: su gives me error setgid: Operation not permitted

Comment: also is there no other way than shifting my entire user account. It's not going to be simple for me. I have a lot of settings stored in my home directory

Comment: @A.B. It didn't work for someone?  And they didn't leave a message why it didn't work?